# Wowza stream protection and expiration

Tags: jwplayer, wowza

I have a Wowza streaming server all set up and 5 streams that are coming from it.I have JWPlayer set on the HTML to play the content.

We're selling tickets to the content and the client would like the tickets to have an expiration or two weeks. I know that after two weeks I could remove the videos, but that would be a global change. How can I make the change for each user? The ticketing platform will allow for unique codes to be given to each purchaser,  But how would I set something like this up?

I've looked though the wowza settings and the JWPlayer settings, but I'm not seeing anything.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Wowza Streaming Engine has a security feature called Secure Token, where you can create tokens and expire them given a specific date. The playback URL that you distribute would be similar to:

```
 http://192.168.1.1:1935/vod/sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8?myTokenPrefixstarttime=1395230400&myTokenPrefixendtime=1500000000&myTokenPrefixCustomP arameter=abcdef&myTokenPrefixhash=TgJft5hsjKyC5Rem_EoUNP7xZvxbqVPhhd0GxIcA2oo=
```

To enable Secure Token, login to the Manager UI, and select Playback Security from the application configuration page. You'll need to have a way to generate these hash tokens. It should be fairly easy with a PHP script. There's also online tools that can do this for you if you need to run a quick test.